# Iphone App Crashes on Device while establishing a DropBox Session

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have made an app which uses DropBox SDK for iPhone to connect to the users dropbox account and upload files. I am using XCode 3.2.5 and the iPhone Simulator is 4.2. My application works great on the simulator, but it crashes when I try it on the device. The following is the line of code where it crashes

```
DBSession* dbSession = [[[DBSession alloc] 
                                 initWithAppKey:kDropBoxAppKey 
                                 appSecret:kDropBoxAppSecret 
                                 root:kDBRootAppFolder] autorelease];
```

When I tried to debug, it could not recognize the object kDBRootAppFolder.

I checked out where this variable was defined, and it was located inside a file of the DropBox SDK called "DBSession.h" as

```
extern NSString *kDBRootAppFolder;
```

While I tried to debug and run it, I found that it showed kDBRootAppFolder was of unknown type.

Then, I tried debugging on the simulator, where it ran perfectly, there the value of kDBRootAppFolder when I printed it was 'sandbox'.

I really dont know why this runtime error is occurring in the device. Please help.

Comment: What was the actual error/cause of the crash? THe debugger's information might well be a red herring in this case because you're building a different profile.

Comment: @quixoto I tried debugging it many times, but could not find the reason why it was giving an error on that part or anywhere else. I even tried replacing kDBRootAppFolder with @"sandbox", as suggested in a forum, but, still it crashed in that particular line.

Comment: What does it say in the console when the crash happens? EXC_BAD_ACCESS? Something else?

Comment: @quixoto Yes, it says EXC_BAD_ACCESS.. I have tried to follow the steps given in the following page, but still, have not been successful... http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=52668&replies=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usually happens when object is released at bad time.

Try this, note the retain in `kDBRootAppFolder`

```
DBSession* dbSession = [[[DBSession alloc] 
                                 initWithAppKey:kDropBoxAppKey 
                                 appSecret:kDropBoxAppSecret 
                                 root:[kDBRootAppFolder retain]] autorelease];
```

if it doesn´t work, use `NSLog(@"%@", kDBRootAppFolder);` before and after the initiation of dbSession to check if is correctly defined.